# How to bulk load data to Apache Phoenix 5.1.2. using Apache Spark 3.2.1?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jar, apache-phoenix

I am trying to bulk load CSV files (30 - 300 GB each) into Apache Phoenix tables. I am trying to do that with the Apache Spark plugin (https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html).
However, when I spark submit my code:

```py
import sys

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('From CSV to Phoenix Loader').getOrCreate()

    csv_name = sys.argv[1]
    table_name = sys.argv[2]

    csv_file = spark.read \
        .option("header", True) \
        .option("delimiter", ",") \
        .csv(f"hdfs://open1:9000/csv_files/{csv_name}")

    csv_file.printSchema()

    csv_file.write \
        .format("phoenix") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("table", table_name) \
        .option("zkUrl", "open1,open2,open3,open4,open5,open6,open7,open8,open9,open10,open11,open12:2181") \
        .save()

    spark.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_from_csv_to_table.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "load_from_csv_to_table.py", line 19, in main
    csv_file.write \
  File "/home/hadoopuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 738, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/home/hadoopuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/home/hadoopuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/hadoopuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: phoenix. Please find packages at
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

My spark-submit:

```bash
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --jars /usr/local/phoenix/phoenix-spark-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar,/usr/local/phoenix/phoenix-client-hbase-2.4-5.1.2.jar hdfs://open1:9000/apps/python/load_from_csv_to_table.py data.csv TABLE.TABLE
```

The problem is, I do not know which JARs should attach to spark submit. When I look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark, I do not see proper JAR version for Apache Phoenix 5.1.2. The last version is 5.0.0 with HBase 2.0.0 from 2018 year. How to bulk load data to Apache Phoenix 5.1.2 using PySpark 3.2.1? Which JARs do I need?

I have also defined spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/local/phoenix/phoenix-client-hbase-2.4-5.1.2.jar:/usr/local/phoenix/phoenix-spark-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/local/phoenix/phoenix-client-hbase-2.4-5.1.2.jar:/usr/local/phoenix/phoenix-spark-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar
```

but I believe the JARs are not proper.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to SparkSession.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('From CSV to Phoenix Loader').config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/phoenix/phoenix-spark-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar").getOrCreate()
```